# Invalidate credentials on Logout with IAM secured AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I'm using an AWS IAM secured AWS API Gateway in conjunction with AWS Cognito Identity Pool, similar to the [Enhanced Simplified Flow described by AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/mobile/understanding-amazon-cognito-authentication-part-4-enhanced-flow/) with an external (OpenId) Login Provider.

Retrieving the credentials is done by:

1. redirect to the Login Provider and obtaining the Id-Token upon successful user authentication,
2. authorize by *AWS Cognito Identity Pool* and assign an authenticated IAM Role,
3. receive the credentials (accessKeyId, secretKey, sessionToken) and
4. access all AWS IAM secured api endpoints with these credentials in an aws-signed request is working fine.

**The problem is in the logout process:**

How can I ensure, that upon logging out the user, the credentials received by the above mentioned process are properly and promptly **not usable anymore** to access the AWS IAM secured endpoints?

I don't see anything related to that in the documentation and to just wait for the credentials to expire is just NOT an option and a quite severe security problem:

***Logging out a user has to prevent user's access to the API-Gateway right away!***

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

We are running into the same set of problems as yours and the AWS Team told us that it is not possible to revoke the tokens immediately after signout/globalSignout. In simple words, signout only invalidates the tokens to prevent uses in Cognito only, other services like API GW or S3 there they check for the expiration of the token in token itself rather than pinging the Cognito for user state verification. Let me know if you managed to solve it!